# FFMPEG avformat_write_header changing my stream time_base

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am muxing video using ffmpeg 2.1.3 with libavcodec 55.39.101 (forced to that version because is the one available in google-chrome PNACL port project). all my frames seems to have bad the time. they try to be rendered all at once at the beggining of the video when playing it.

I am setting the stream time base to 1/25, but just after calling avformat_write_header, it has the value of -18082736/1.
in each frame, when I print the stream time_base it says 1/12800, while the time_base of codec is always ok (1/25).

console log before and after av_format_write_header:

```
before avformat_write_header stream time_base: 1/25
after avformat_write_header ret 0 stream time_base: -18082736/1
```

the code (abreviated to keep the post short, all calls in the original version had error checking):

```
AVCodecContext *codecContext;
AVCodec * codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);  
myOutputStream->stream = avformat_new_stream(outputFormatContext, *codec);
myOutputStream->stream->id = outputFormatContext->nb_streams-1;
codecContext = myOutputStream->stream->codec;
codecContext->codec_id = codec_id;
codecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
codecContext->width    = width;
codecContext->height   = height;
myOutputStream->stream->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, 25 };
codecContext->time_base       = myOutputStream->stream->time_base;
codecContext->gop_size      = 12; 
codecContext->pix_fmt       = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
AVDictionary *opt = NULL;
av_dict_copy(&opt, opt_arg, 0);
ret = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, &opt);
av_dict_free(&opt);
myOutputStream->frame = alloc_picture(codecContext->pix_fmt, codecContext->width, codecContext->height);
  myOutputStream->tmp_frame = alloc_picture(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, codecContext->width, codecContext->height);

//before: printing g_outputContext->stream time_base here
ret = avformat_write_header(g_outputContext, &opt);
//after: printing g_outputContext->stream time_base here
```

If I run ffmpeg -i on the final video, I got this (why duration is zero?):

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
  Duration: 00:00:00.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 99549 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 800x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 463106 kb/s, 12800 fps, 12800 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Comment: Have you found a proper solution for this issue?

Comment: Why @RafaelLucio answer is not marked as correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to manipulate the pts of the packet after encoding and before writing to the file... Its not unusual to have the time_base of the stream changed by ffmpeg. Check line 869 of the ffmpeg.c source code at https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/ffmpeg_8c-source.html

Comment: I spent almost 1 day to find why my pts were changed. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what "manipulate the pts of the packet" would mean? Will it make the resulting video have the FPS which had been defined in the beginning when setting time_base?

Answer (score 3):

To add more details to @RafaelLucio [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29855252/213871), `avformat_write_header` modify the stream time base by design and the frame pts must be properly computed before sending it to the codec context, rescaling the desired value to actual stream time base. A simple solution is keeping a pts counter outside the frame append function and compute the next pts in the function body.

```c
int64_t pts = 0;
AVCodecContext *codecCtx;
AVStream *stream;

void appendFrame(AVFrame *frame)
{
    [...]
    frame->pts = pts;
    // Compute next pts
    pts += av_rescale_q(1, codecCtx->time_base, stream->time_base);
    [...]
}
```